# mistake in multivePenal but not in frailtyPenal

Tags: r

The libraries used are: library(survival)
library(splines)
library(boot)
library(frailtypack) and the function used is in the library frailty pack.
In my data I have two recurrent events(delta.stable and delta.unstable)  and one terminal event (delta.censor). There are some  time-varying explanatory variables, like unemployment rate(u.rate) (is quarterly) that's why my dataset has been splitted by quarters. 
Here there is a link to the subsample used in the code just below, just in case it may be  helpful to see the mistake.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/spfywobydr94bml/cr_05_males_services.rda
The problem is that it takes a lot of time running until the warning message appear.

Main variables of the Survival function are:
I have two recurrent events:
    delta.unstable (unst.): takes value one when the individual find an unstable job.
    delta.stable (stable): takes value one when the individual find a stable job.
    And one terminal event
    delta.censor (d.censor): takes value one when the individual has death, retired or emigrated.

```
row     id contadorbis unst. stable d.censor    .t0 .t
1   78  1   0   1   0   0   88
2   101 2   0   1   0   0   46
3   155 3   0   1   0   0   27
4   170 4   0   0   0   0   61
5   170 4   1   0   0   61  86
6   213 5   0   0   0   0   92
7   213 5   0   0   0   92  182
8   213 5   0   0   0   182 273
9   213 5   0   0   0   273 365
10  213 5   1   0   0   365 394
11  334 6   0   1   0   0   6
12  334 7   1   0   0   0   38
13  369 8   0   0   0   0   27
14  369 8   0   0   0   27  119
15  369 8   0   0   0   119 209
16  369 8   0   0   0   209 300
17  369 8   0   0   0   300 392
```

When I apply `multivePenal` I obtain the following message:

```
Error en aggregate.data.frame(as.data.frame(x), ...) : 
arguments must have same length
Además: Mensajes de aviso perdidos

In Surv(.t0, .t, delta.stable) : Stop time must be > start time, NA created
#### multivePenal function
fit.joint.05_malesP<multivePenal(Surv(.t0,.t,delta.stable)~cluster(contadorbis)+terminal(as.factor(delta.censor))+event2(delta.unstable),formula.terminalEvent=~1, formula2=~as.factor(h.skill),data=cr_05_males_serv,Frailty=TRUE,recurrentAG=TRUE,cross.validation=F,n.knots=c(7,7,7), kappa=c(1,1,1), maxit=1000, hazard="Splines")
```

I have checked if `Surv(.t0,.t,delta.stable)` contains `NA`, and there are no `NA`'s.

In addition, when I apply for the same data the function `frailtyPenal` for both possible combinations, the function run well and I get results. I take one week looking at this and I do not find the key. I would appreciate some of light to this problem.

```
#delta unstable+death

enter code here

fit.joint.05_males<-frailtyPenal(Surv(.t0,.t,delta.unstable)~cluster(id)+u.rate+as.factor(h.skill)+as.factor(m.skill)+as.factor(non.manual)+as.factor(municipio)+as.factor(spanish.speakers)+ as.factor(no.spanish.speaker)+as.factor(Aged.16.19)+as.factor(Aged.20.24)+as.factor(Aged.25.29)+as.factor(Aged.30.34)+as.factor(Aged.35.39)+ as.factor(Aged.40.44)+as.factor(Aged.45.51)+as.factor(older61)+ as.factor(responsabilities)+
terminal(delta.censor),formula.terminalEvent=~u.rate+as.factor(h.skill)+as.factor(m.skill)+as.factor(municipio)+as.factor(spanish.speakers)+as.factor(no.spanish.speaker)+as.factor(Aged.16.19)+as.factor(Aged.20.24)+as.factor(Aged.25.29)+as.factor(Aged.30.34)+as.factor(Aged.35.39)+as.factor(Aged.40.44)+as.factor(Aged.45.51)+as.factor(older61)+ as.factor(responsabilities),data=cr_05_males_services,n.knots=12,kappa1=1000,kappa2=1000,maxit=1000, Frailty=TRUE,joint=TRUE, recurrentAG=TRUE)

###Be patient. The program is computing ... 
###The program took 2259.42 seconds 

#delta stable+death
fit.joint.05_males<frailtyPenal(Surv(.t0,.t,delta.stable)~cluster(id)+u.rate+as.factor(h.skill)+as.factor(m.skill)+as.factor(non.manual)+as.factor(municipio)+as.factor(spanish.speakers)+as.factor(no.spanish.speaker)+as.factor(Aged.16.19)+as.factor(Aged.20.24)+as.factor(Aged.25.29)+as.factor(Aged.30.34)+as.factor(Aged.35.39)+as.factor(Aged.40.44)+as.factor(Aged.45.51)+as.factor(older61)+as.factor(responsabilities)+terminal(delta.censor),formula.terminalEvent=~u.rate+as.factor(h.skill)+as.factor(m.skill)+as.factor(municipio)+as.factor(spanish.speakers)+as.factor(no.spanish.speaker)+as.factor(Aged.16.19)+as.factor(Aged.20.24)+as.factor(Aged.25.29)+as.factor(Aged.30.34)+as.factor(Aged.35.39)+as.factor(Aged.40.44)+as.factor(Aged.45.51)+as.factor(older61)+as.factor(responsabilities),data=cr_05_males_services,n.knots=12,kappa1=1000,kappa2=1000,maxit=1000, Frailty=TRUE,joint=TRUE, recurrentAG=TRUE)
###The program took 3167.15 seconds
```

Comment: You should provide information what libraries do you use. I assume it is frailtypack but it maybe not obvious for everyone. Also your example is using cr_05_males_services you should provide some example how it looks like.

Comment: Please add [necessary information on used packages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). Please check your code and data sets _carefully_. E.g. I suppose the `<` here `fit.joint.05_malesP<multivePenal` should be a `<-`. Please post example data that actually contains the _same_ variables as in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Because you neither [provide information about the packages used, nor the data necessary to run `multivepenal` or `frailtyPenal`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610), I can only help you with the `Surv` part (because I happened to have that package loaded).

The `Surv` warning message you provided (`In Surv(.t0, .t, delta.stable) : Stop time must be > start time, NA created`) suggests that something is strange with your variables `.t0` (the `time` argument in `Surv`, refered to as 'start time' in the warning), and/or `.t` (`time2` argument, 'Stop time' in the warning). I check this possibility with a simple example

```
# read the data you feed `Surv` with
df <- read.table(text = "row     id contadorbis unst. stable d.censor    .t0 .t
1   78  1   0   1   0   0   88
2   101 2   0   1   0   0   46
3   155 3   0   1   0   0   27
4   170 4   0   0   0   0   61
5   170 4   1   0   0   61  86
6   213 5   0   0   0   0   92
7   213 5   0   0   0   92  182
8   213 5   0   0   0   182 273
9   213 5   0   0   0   273 365
10  213 5   1   0   0   365 394
11  334 6   0   1   0   0   6
12  334 7   1   0   0   0   38
13  369 8   0   0   0   0   27
14  369 8   0   0   0   27  119
15  369 8   0   0   0   119 209
16  369 8   0   0   0   209 300
17  369 8   0   0   0   300 392", header = TRUE)

# create survival object
mysurv <- with(df, Surv(time = .t0, time2 = .t, event = stable))
mysurv

# create a new data set where one .t for some reason is less than .to
# on row five .t0 is 61, so I set .t to 60
df2 <- df
df2$.t[df2$.t == 86] <- 60

# create survival object using new data which contains at least one Stop time that is less than Start time
mysurv2 <- with(df2, Surv(time = .t0, time2 = .t, event = stable))

# Warning message:
#  In Surv(time = .t0, time2 = .t, event = stable) :
#  Stop time must be > start time, NA created
# i.e. the same warning message as you got

# check the survival object
mysurv2

# as you can see, the fifth interval contains NA
# I would recommend you check .t0 and .t in your data set carefully 
# one way to examine rows where Stop time (.t) is less than start time (.t0) is:
df2[which(df2$.t0 > df2$.t), ]
```

I am not familiar with `multivepenal` but it seems that it does not accept a survival object which contains intervals with NA, whereas might `frailtyPenal` might do so.

Comment: Thank you! Please add this information at the very start of your script in your question. Everything in the spirit of posting [a minimal, reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610)! With the necessary **runnable code**, you are much more likely to receive a helpful answer. And since you are new on SO, you may [read this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to get an idea of what to do when someone answers your question.

Comment: I have done what you suggested to my data frame and the answer is: 0 rows> (or 0-length row.names) in which .t<.t0 so I would appreciate more suggestions.I have included the libraries used and the link to my dataset.

Comment: In my tiny example, I explicitly told `Surv` to look for the variables in the data frame `df` and `df2` by using `with`. In your script, you are not referring to a specific data frame you call `Surv`. Is it possible that you have separate vectors called .t0, and .t laying around in your workspace that are used by `Surv`? I suggest you to start with a _clean workspace_, and run `Surv` in a first, separate step, specifically referring to the relevant data frame using `with` (similar to my small example).

Comment: Sorry, a typo. Should be: "a specific data frame in your call to `Surv`"

Comment: I have done this:
df2 <- cr_05_males_serv
mysurv2 <- with(df2, Surv(time = .t0, time2 = .t, event = delta.stable))
mysurv2
> mysurv2[which(.t0 > .t), ]
[1] (,] Neither it is satisfied.

Comment: I am afraid I don't quite follow what you have done. Sorry. Can you please upload a text file with the data you are using in `Surv` to Dropbox. I have trouble with your the .rda file you posted before.

Comment: I managed to download cr_05_males_serv.rda. ('data.frame':71205 obs. of  47 variables). No .t < .t0. I had no problems to run `with(cr_05_males_serv, Surv(time = .t0, time2 = .t, event = delta.stable))`. Have you tried to use this survival object in `multivePenal`? The error you received was from running **`Surv`**. If **I** don't get the errors when I run `Surv`, using the same variables, it seems likely you had variables lurking around on your workspace where some .t were < .t0.

Comment: The problem comes when I run multivePenal(The code is in my question) and the answer that I received is that related with Survival.I really do not understand the mistake, because, as you have seen Survival is ok.Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Yes, `Surv` runs fine **with the data set you posted**. But, I repeat, the warning message `Stop time must be > start time` comes from `Surv`. Thus, you must have used another dataset where a .t happened to be < .t0.

Comment: I am using exactly that dataset. And for this dataset Surv runs well but multivepenal does not do, that is what I do not understand.Have you tried to run multivepenal with the dataset that works well with Surv??? I can not see what happen.

Answer (score 0):

The authors of the package have told me that the function is not finished yet, so perhaps that is the reason that it is not working well.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error and arrived at this solution.

`frailtyPenal()` will not accept `data.frames` of different length. The `data.frame` used in `Surv` and `data.frame` named in `data=` in `frailtyPenal` must be the same length. I used a Cox regression to identify the incomplete cases, reset the survival object to exclude the missing cases and, finally, run `frailtyPenal`:

```
library(survival)
library(frailtypack)

data(readmission)

#Reproduce the error

#change the first start time to NA
  readmission[1,3] <- NA 

#create a survival object with one missing time
  surv.obj1 <- with(readmission, Surv(t.start, t.stop, event))

#observe the error
  frailtyPenal(surv.obj1 ~ cluster(id) + dukes, 
               data=readmission, 
               cross.validation=FALSE,
               n.knots=10,
               kappa=1,
               hazard="Splines")

#repair by resetting the surv object to omit the missing value(s)

#identify NAs using a Cox model
  cox.na <- coxph(surv.obj1 ~ dukes, data = readmission)

#remove the NA cases from the original set to create complete cases
  readmission2 <- readmission[-cox.na$na.action,]

#reset the survival object using the complete cases
  surv.obj2 <- with(readmission2, Surv(t.start, t.stop, event))

#run frailtyPenal using the complete cases dataset and the complete cases Surv object
  frailtyPenal(surv.obj2 ~ cluster(id) + dukes,
               data = readmission2, 
               cross.validation = FALSE,
               n.knots = 10,
               kappa = 1,
               hazard = "Splines")
```